# LinkedIn : Marketing Developer Platform Stuck in Review process

Tags: linkedin-api

I have created a product request in LinkedIn for the Marketing Developer Platform on 24th May, but still its on "Review in Progress". Can anyone suggest me, When will I get review/feedback?

Comment: SO isn't the right platform to ask this question. Visit [SO LinkedIn Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) for more info.

Comment: **LinkedIn Tag clearly says:** This tag is used for questions regarding LinkedIn's APIs. Do not ask questions about LinkedIn's terms of service, problems with registering for a service with them, or what APIs they will be offering in the future. They are not appropriate for asking on Stack Overflow, *even if* LinkedIn appeared to direct you here.

Comment: Thanks for the qucik reply @AadityaSharma However , I have found one more thread for the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854037/marketing-developer-platform-stuck-review. It would be appreciable if you know and share the details to connect with LinkedIn to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer service request for LinkedIn

Comment: It's sad that LinkedIn doesn't care enough to actually have developer support and are instead sending people here.